# changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpamld**

**Question:** Can someone help me understand why my prototype's `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` still allows me to update the inner value `name`? If this is not what `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` suppose to prevent, what should it be doing?

**app.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public name = 'Angular 5';
  public changeName() {
    this.name = 'Outer';
  }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<button (click)="changeName()">Outter Change</button>
<p>{{name}}-- outer</p>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

**hello.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1> <button (click)="changeName()">inner Change</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;


  public changeName() {
    this.name = 'Inner';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because primitive datatype is immutable - if you change it, its reference also changes, so `ChangeDetectorRef`of your component knows it must detect changes (because `OnPush` looks for references changes, not data mutations in arrays, objects). If you want to avoid that on primitives, you can manually deactivate/activate this on ChangeDetectorRef instance with `detach()`/ `reattach()`:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

 constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public changeName() {
    this.ref.detach();
    this.name = 'Inner';
  }
}
```

Comment: Just another qq how would you tell if `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` is working properly? w/o detaching the ref?  Marking correct regardless.

Comment: @J.D. But then the inner change method will freeze and will not work any more  ?

Comment: @Matthew Harwood Here is a great article - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html basically when app state changes, ngZones fires an event that goes through ChangeDetectorReferences and invokes `detectChanges()` on each

Comment: @Rahul Singh - yes, because ChangeDetector runs on a whole component tree. And it will nor `freeze` it will just not change the view. You can perform logic on that method

Comment: Yes but that flaws the use of the inner method thow better to check for changes and act accordingly

Comment: @Rahul Singh - Maybe. I cant say what OP really needs

Answer (score 3):

The default change detection strategy is to be conservative and check all its bindings for something that ***might*** have changed.  Typically, a change detection cycle is triggered whenever an *[input]* changes, or an *(event)* occurs from *any* component.

By changing a component's change detection strategy to *OnPush*, Angular only checks for updates when the component's inputs ***have*** actually changed. This allows Angular to be more efficient with change detection by allowing entire sub-trees to be skipped during change detection.

Here is a good article on it: https://vsavkin.com/immutability-vs-encapsulation-90549ab74487

Some points to help with the understanding is:

1. By default, when a change detection digest is triggered, all bindings are checked for updates from all components, regardless of where the change originally came from.
2. Change detection occurs to establish the original bindings (Input Bindings) or it can be triggered by a browser event (i.e. Output Bindings).  Once triggered, #1 applies.
3. Change detection occurs top-down, starting from the root component towards the leaves. Think of this as a unidirectional tree of connected components, that starts with an AppComponent for the root.
4. When a component's change detection strategy is changed to `OnPush` then during change detection, it will skip a component's entire sub-tree if the inputs have not changed.

Answer (score 2):

> The state is updated only if parent view bindings changed and child
>   component view was initialized with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

In the Example you stated just add the following lines to the child Hello Component.

```
 ngOnChanges(simpleChange : SimpleChanges){
   console.log(simpleChange)
  }
```

You will see that that upon click of a button the view changes as the parent Bindings has changes that is the reason the view is updated in both parent and Child.